# How to remove a string between two strings ("Mapping=" and ">")?

Tags: regex, notepad++

How remove part of a string in a line like:

```
FROMFIELD ="DTA_SCORING_7" Mapping="T_STG_GKAP" > SHORTCUT COMMENTS ="" FOLDERNAME ="MTD";

FROMFIELD ="DTA_SCORING_7" Mapping="Tfsdfsdfsdf" > SHORTCUT COMMENTS ="" FOLDERNAME ="MTD";
```

I'd like to remove, from each line this is occurring, the part between "`Mapping=`" and "`>`". How can I achieve this using a regex in [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)?

Comment: If the string starts at the same position at every line, you might use `ALT` + cursor to select a column and then just press delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<=Mapping=)(.*?)(?=>)
```

I used lookbehind (`?<=`) and look ahead (`?=`) so that `"Mapping="` and `">"` is not included in the match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qQ5mH6/2)